# Using ajax to print "Hello World!" when you click a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to print "Hello World!", when you click a button, but it's not working, for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

**test1.php**

```
#testID {
border: 1px solid purple;
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
}

<?php

$commentID = "commentID";
$comment = "comment";

echo "
<input  type = 'submit' value = 'Post' onclick = \"ajaxPass('test2.php', $comment, $commentID,'testID')\">
<div id = 'testID'></div>
";

?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajaxPass(action,comment,commentID,outputID) {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: action,
data: { comment: comment, commentID: commentID },
error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
success:function(data) {
document.getElementById(outputID).innerHTML = data;        
} //end of success:function(data)
}); //end of $.ajax({

} //end of function ajaxPass(action,comment,commentID,outputID)

</script>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

echo "Hello World!";

?>
```

Comment: The syntax of your onclick attribute is wrong. do a view-source on your web page to see how it outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your code. Your `echo` statement should be like this:

```
echo "<input  type = 'submit' value = 'Post' onclick = \"ajaxPass('post.php', '{$comment}', '{$commentID}','testID')\"><div id = 'testID'></div>";
```

Use `ctrl+u` on your browser to see the source code, and check what's there in `onclick` attribute.

And also add this div `<div id="outputID"></div>` in your **test1.php** page.

Comment: Wait. You mean the only part was that you have to wrap php variables in brackets and single quotes when echoing them?!!!!

Comment: @frosty Yes, that's it.

Comment: I feel like screaming. I've been spending hours trying to find out exactly where I went wrong...Thanks!